# Run several microservices docker image together on local dev with Minikube

Tags: spring-boot, docker, kubernetes, minikube

I have several microservices around 20 or something to check their services in my local development. The micro-services are spring boot services with maven build. So wanted to know when I have to run them on my aws server can I run all these containers individually like they might have shared database so will that be one issue i might face.Or is it possible to run all these services together in one single docker image.
Also I have to configure it with Kubernetes so I have configured Minikube in my local dev would be helpful if there are some considerations to be taken while running around 20services on my minikube or even Kubernetes env

PS: I know this is a basic question but dont have much idea about Devops

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you should have different docker image for each of the micro services and create kubernetes [deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/) for each of the micro services.This makes scaling individual micro services de coupled from each other. Also  communication between micro services should be via kubernetes [service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/). This makes communication stable because service IPs and FQDN don't change even if pods are created, deleted, scaled up and down.

Just be cautious of how much memory and CPU the micros services will need and if the system with minikube has that much resource or not. If the available memory and CPU of a Kubernetes node is not enough to schedule the pod then pods will be stuck in pending state.

Answer (score 0):

As you have too many microservices, I suggest you make a Kubernetes cluster on AWS of 3-4 VMs ([more info here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-kubernetes-cluster-using-kubeadm-on-ubuntu-18-04)). Then try to deploy all your microservices on that. For that you need to build the containers individually for each service and create kubernetes deployment for each service.

> I run all these containers individually like they might have shared database so will that be one issue i might face.

As you have shared database, I suggest you run your database server on individual host and then remotely connect with your database from your services. This way you would be able to share database between your microservices.